# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring

I got this error when I ran my very first spring example code. It looks like spring does not

reconize a bean somehow but I dont know why. I made a bean definition file and added one bean there.

Then I located that file under WEBINF folder. Supposely this should work without any issue but looks

like I got some issues here. below is my bean definition file and jsp. can anybody tell me

what am I doing wrong?

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="HelloSpring" class="com.spring.toby.HelloSpring"></bean>

</beans>
```

HelloSpring.java

```
package com.spring.toby;

public class HelloSpring {
public String sayHello(String name){
    return "Hello " + name;
}
}
```

HelloSpring.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"
pageEncoding="EUC-KR"%>
<%@ page import="org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext" %>    
<%@ page import="org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils" %>    
<%@ page import="com.spring.toby.HelloSpring" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
    ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
    request.getSession().getServletContext());
    out.println("check");
    HelloSpring helloSpring = context.getBean(HelloSpring.class);

    //out.println(helloSpring.sayHello("seho"));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   /web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and here is my error log

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/views/hellospring.jsp at line 17

14:         ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(
15:         request.getSession().getServletContext());
16:         out.println("check");
17:         HelloSpring helloSpring = context.getBean(HelloSpring.class);
18:
19:         //out.println(helloSpring.sayHello("seho"));
20:     %>

```
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.spring.toby.HelloSpring] is defined: expected single bean but found 0: 
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:271)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1101)
    org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.hellospring_jsp._jspService(hellospring_jsp.java:81)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1157)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:927)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: Are you sure, that you using right context file? Post content of your `web.xml` pls.

Comment: I added web.xml. oh... now I see.. do I include applicationContext.xml to context-param?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `applicationContext.xml` in contextConfigLocation

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml,
                 /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml
     </param-value>
</context-param>
```

Alternatively you could also import bean defination from another file using `<import:resource>` tag in xml file

---

**Suggestion**

It is good practice to put logic on controllers (Servlet, Controller Classes..) not on JSP

Comment: um.. can you tell me where is comtextconfiglocaton in default STS?

Comment: in web.xml you need to specify the config locations, now when listener starts it will look for the config files at mentioned locations, I hope I have answered your question